# How can I change the default math-mode 'f' in the cochineal package?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, italic, newtxmath

I think the font provided by [the `cochineal` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/cochineal) is excellent, and I want to write documents using it, so I use the following in my preamble:

```
\usepackage[osf, p]{cochineal}
\usepackage[cochineal]{newtxmath}
```

However I dislike one particular change that was made in the math font, namely the way that italic `f` is changed. See the difference in the line `\textit{f} versus $f$`:
[image: the visual difference in regular italics and math mode letter 'f']

As far as I can tell this is one of three changes to the lowercase italic alphabet in math mode: the letters `v` and `w` are also changed to have better distinction from the greek letter nu.

My issue is that I strongly dislike this new letter `f`. I understand this may have been a stylistic choice by the designer but I much prefer the reclining, two-tailed f to this one.

I can force the math `f` to display as the regular italic one by writing `\mathit{f}` rather than just `f`, but this is obviously not very convenient.

**How can I change the way that the lowercase letter `f` is displayed in math mode?**

---

Here is a minimal document to reproduce this: (compiled with pdfTeX)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[osf, p]{cochineal}
\usepackage[cochineal]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
Comparison: \textit{f} versus $f$.

Default: $f(x + y) = f(2x) + f(2y) - 1$.

Forced italic: $\mathit{f}(x + y) = \mathit{f}(2x) + \mathit{f}(2y) - 1$.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a new math symbol font.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[osf, p]{cochineal}
\usepackage[cochineal]{newtxmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cochinealit}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{f}{\mathalpha}{cochinealit}{`f}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathit}{cochinealit}

\begin{document}

Comparison: \textit{f} versus $f$. Also $f^2$.

Default: $f(x + y) = f(2x) + f(2y) - 1$.

Forced italic: $\mathit{f}(x + y) = \mathit{f}(2x) + \mathit{f}(2y) - 1$.

Beware: $ff+f\/f$

Math roman: $\mathrm{f}$

\end{document}
```

There's a small catch, shown in the last line: you need something like `f\/f` if two consecutive `f`'s appear in a formula.

[image]

Comment: This is very explanatory. I wonder if there is any way to automatically supress ligatures here?

Comment: @AJFarmar Not without much labor: the font needs to be duplicated to be loaded at a slightly (but unnoticeable) different size and its internal parameter be changed.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\showoutput
\usepackage[osf, p]{cochineal}
\usepackage[cochineal]{newtxmath}
\sbox0{$\mathit{abc}$}


\mathcode`f=\numexpr\mathcode`f+"700\relax

\begin{document}


Comparison: \textit{f} versus $f$.

Default: $f(x + y) = f(2x) + f(2y) - 1$.

Forced italic: $\mathit{f}(x + y) = \mathit{f}(2x) + \mathit{f}(2y) - 1$.

Forced roman: $\mathrm{f}(x + y) = \mathrm{f}(2x) + \mathrm{f}(2y) - 1$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you forget something?

Comment: @egreg there are lots of things I didn't mention, if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

The newest version of the `newtxmath` package supports two new options, `cochf` and `cochrho` which change the `f` in mathmode to the requested one, and of `\rho` to `\rhoAlt`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[p,osf]{cochineal}
\usepackage[cochf,cochrho,cochineal]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\emph{elf} and $f\in F$ and $\rho\rhoAlt$

\emph{effective} and $ff\in F$

\end{document}
```

[image: alt f and rho]

Answer (score 0):

One hacky way is to change the letter `f` to an active character, but only in math mode. This is described in [this post on the TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-activechars).

We do this by inserting this:

```
% Warning: there are serious issues with this; see below.
\begingroup
\lccode`~=`f
\lowercase{\endgroup
    \def~{\text{\textit{f}}}%
}%
\mathcode`f="8000
```

Put simply, this replace all occurences of the solitary letter `f` with `\text{\textit{f}}` in math mode.

So, here's a full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[osf, p]{cochineal}
\usepackage[cochineal]{newtxmath}


\begingroup
\lccode`~=`f
\lowercase{\endgroup
    \def~{\text{\textit{f}}}%
}%
\mathcode`f="8000

\begin{document}
Comparison: \textit{f} versus $f$.


Default: $f(x + y) = f(2x) + f(2y) - 1$.

Forced italic: $\mathit{f}(x + y) = \mathit{f}(2x) + \mathit{f}(2y) - 1$.
\end{document}
```

This produces the desired result:[image: Result with catcode change]

**There are serious issues with this**. In particular, `\mathrm{f}` displays strictly in italic, so for instance `\liminf` has a jarring italic `f` at the end.

For this reason, it may be preferable simply to define `\newcommand\f{\mathit{f}}` and simply write `\f(x)` instead of `f(x)`.